# Train two consecutive models in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a model in tensorflow, while I use two consecutive models. Unfortunately I can't include them within one model. The first Model is basically an encoder, the second returns my needed value.

```
out = Model_a(image_input)
value = Model_b(out)
loss = f(value)
```

I can train Model_b using the given loss, but would then need the gradients of the first layer (of Model_b) regarding the loss to proceed for the gradient calculation in Model_a. Furthermore I would need somehow a function that calculates the gradients based on these gradients, instead of a loss function. Does anyone have an idea if tensorflow already has such functionality or had to tackle similar problems?

Cheers

Comment: check out kera's sklearn integration for working with sklearn pipelines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, for any who has similar problems. Using Tensorflow 2.0 and the keras eager-mode (using GradientTape) one can construct any loss function as desired, even including consecutive models. Important is that the predict function will not work, one needs to use the direct call.
Now the gradients can be calculated for each model regarding that loss function, which seems to work so far. Important is that the models itself are included in the loss function and not a copy of the output or at least the copy is generated within the Tape environment. An example is found below:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    error = (model2(model1(x)) - y)
    loss_value = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))
gradients1 = tape.gradient(loss_value, model1.variables)
gradients2 = tape.gradient(loss_value, model2.variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients1, model1.variables))
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients2, model2.variables))
```

If anyone finds a more efficient or "prettier" solution I would be happy if he/she shares it.

Cheers